# Do CopyFile and CopyFileEx work if the source file is open?

Tags: winapi, vba

I want to call a copyFile function from within the source file to be copied. The VBA FileCopy function does not allow the source file to be open while it is copied. I am thinking of using CopyFile or CopyFileEx (to show a progress bar) instead.

Therefore, do those functions work if the source file is open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, CopyFileEx() has the COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE option, allowing you to copy a file that was opened for writing.  You'd still need cooperation from the owner of the file, it would have had to open the file allowing read sharing.

Beware of the trouble you can get into with this option, you'll essentially get a random snapshot of the file, you could copy the file while the app was in the middle of writing to the file.  Such a copy isn't usually readable anymore.  You'd be lucky if the app trying to read such a copy crashes and dies.  But the more likely outcome is subtly corrupt data.

Comment: From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): *`COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE` - The file is copied and the original file is opened for write access.* ... I'd say the docs are clear as mud, but it really doesn't sound like what you say above.

Comment: For an actually correct explanation of what the C.F.O._SRC_FOR_WRITE flag actually does, see: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230215-00/?p=107832#comment-140208

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, Win32 [`CopyFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) and [`CopyFileEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexa) (and [`CopyFile2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile2)) all *will* open a file that is already open by someone else, as long as the other party has specified `FILE_SHARE_READ`.

Specifically, my latest tries (on Windows 10 1809) show that these function will try to open the file

- 1st, with `GENERIC_READ` + `FILE_SHARE_READ` - thus blocking any later writers.
- 2nd, transparently(!), fall back to `GENERIC_READ` + `FILE_SHARE_READ & FILE_SHARE_WRITE` if someone else has the file already open for write access, thereby even copying a file that is written by someone else.